# Email migration and multidomain account

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk

I'm using the [Google data Python client library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) to import emails into my users account.

If this is working fine for users in the primary domain, I get an error for users in a separate domain.

```
from gdata.apps.migration import service

user  = "user@example.fr"
admin = "admin@example.com"
admin_pwd = "hackme"

srv = service.MigrationService(email = admin, password = admin_pwd, domain = "example.com")
```

So if I set `domain` to the primary one, I get the following error message when I try to submit the batch:

```
gdata.apps.service.AppsForYourDomainException: {'status': 403, 'body': '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Authorization failed.  Ensure that the destination user exists and try again.</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n<H1>Authorization failed.  Ensure that the destination user exists and try again.</H1>\n<H2>Error 403</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n', 'reason': 'Authorization failed.  Ensure that the destination user exists and try again.'}
```

If I set no domain name, I get this one instead:

```
gdata.apps.service.AppsForYourDomainException: {'status': 403, 'body': '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Invalid domain.</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n<H1>Invalid domain.</H1>\n<H2>Error 403</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n', 'reason': 'Invalid domain.'}
```

I can understand why I get those errors but the question is: can I import users emails on a separate domain? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you really should be using the [new Email Migration API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-migration/) along with the [google-api-python-client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/) for this rather than the [old and deprecated GData-based API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-migration/v1/index).

Having said that, it should just be a matter of setting the domain value to that of the user mailbox you wisht to migrate mail into rather than the admin domain:

```
user  = "user@example.fr"
admin = "admin@example.com"
admin_pwd = "hackme"

srv = service.MigrationService(email = admin, password = admin_pwd, domain = "example.fr")
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how to migrate emails using the new API but anyway it works if I set `domain` to the user's domain and then use only the user key when submitting.

Comment: Feel free to post a new question covering your issues using the new API and post the link here, I'll do my best to answer them also.